# Examples of topologies between norm and weak star

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a normed vector space and $X^\ast$ denote its continuous dual. The norm on $X^\ast$ is given by $\|\varphi\|=\sup_{\|x\|=1}|\varphi(x)|$. The weak star topology on $X^\ast$ is the weakest (=coarsets) topology such that all the maps $e_x:X^\ast \to \mathbb C$, $\varphi \mapsto \varphi (x)$ are continuous.

What are possible ways of defining a topology that lies strictly between the norm topology and the weak star topology?

Comment: The weak topology in an infinite dimensional space lies strictly between the norm and the weak topologies. Or am I mistaken?

Comment: If the space is reflexive, the weak topology is the same as the weak* topology, @Frank.

Comment: The set up needs to be clarified: you begin with "$X$ is a topological vector space", but in the second sentence $X$ turns out to have a norm.

Comment: @cheapeffectivedietpills Thanks, you're right it was a typo. I corrected it.